# Rcpp project clean and rebuild

Tags: c++, r, rstudio, rcpp

I'm trying to build the sample hello world file that comes by default when an Rcpp package project is created in RStudio on Mac.
I'm using latest version of RStudio (Version 1.3.959) and R (4.0.2). The clang version is 11.0.3 and have the command line tools installed.

Unlike the expected compile output of rcpp_hello_world.cpp to create .o objects I see that in my project, RStudio uses R and tries to byte-compile, avoiding the C compilation.

I also updated the Makeconf for gnu++17

(CXX = clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++17)

I haev installed Rcpp, RcppEigen and BH packages and created a new Rcpp project and I updated the NAMESPACE file to recognize the Rcpp tags for interface functions.

Here is the output I got:

```
==> Rcpp::compileAttributes()

* Updated R/RcppExports.R

==> R CMD INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --with-keep.source RcppPackage003a

* installing to library ‘/Users/username/Library/R/4.0/library’
* installing *source* package ‘RcppPackage003a’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RcppPackage003a’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘RcppPackage003a.so’ not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
```

Any pointers on what I could be doing wrong and why it's not trying to compile the src files?

As a quick Rcpp install test I was able to call a C++ function from R (referring this doc - http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/Rcpp.pdf)

by sourcing a test cpp file with following function -

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]

void hello()
{
 Rprintf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

and then in R console calling the hello function after sourcing the cpp file:

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp("hello.cpp")

hello()
```

How can I debug the missing link where it is not picking up the cpp file to be compiled?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  _If_ you are using a _package_ you never EVER use `sourceCpp()` inside the package. The `sourceCpp()` helper is for ad-hoc, at the prompt, work.   To make changes in a package, you rebuild and reload.  RStudio has a button for that.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response Dirk, yes as you said, I used sourceCpp just to check whether my Rcpp install was fine or not. But when it comes to building the package in RStudio, I'm getting the following messages (also mentioned in the original question) Typically it should be compiling the .cpp files but not sure why RStudio is ignoring the cpp files even though it is an Rcpp package project - ==> Rcpp::compileAttributes()

Updated R/RcppExports.R
==> R CMD INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --with-keep.source RcppPackage003a

Comment: R CMD INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --with-keep.source RcppPackage003a

installing to library ‘/Users/username/Library/R/4.0/library’
installing source package ‘RcppPackage003a’ ... ** using staged installation ** R ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading ** help *** installing help indices ** building package indices ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RcppPackage003a’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib): shared object ‘RcppPackage003a.so’ not found Error: loading failed Execution halted

Comment: This illegible in the comment.  Can you maybe place it in the main question?  Also---consider starting *clean* with a fresh package generated from the helpers, and build that a few times. Works for others.

Comment: Thanks, reformatted the output under "Here is the output I got:" in the main question. Can you please elaborate more about "generated from the helpers"?

Comment: The recommended sequence of steps is to a) first build a tar.gz and then b) install the tar.gz.  Other things could be going on here too --- I can't really help you given the information.  You show _errors_, we need the _causes of errors_.

Comment: Also: "RStudio uses R and tries to byte-compile, avoiding the C compilation."  No, that is not what is happening.  I think you are trying to juggle with seven balls.  Tackle the different problems one by one.